# PowerShell: Get-NetTCPConnection script that also shows Username & Process Name

Tags: windows, powershell, netstat

I created a script to output `Get-NetTCPConnection` data but additionally show **Process Name** and **Username**. The script *does* work, but I would love any tips to simplify or make this more canonical.

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to add the `ProcessName` and `Username` to the output without having to preload the values into the custom PSObject (`$obj` array). I am concerned that the custom `e={($obj |? PID -eq $_.OwningProcess | select -ExpandProperty UserName)}}` expression is overly complex.

```
$obj=@()

Foreach($p In (Get-Process -IncludeUserName | where {$_.UserName} | `
  select Id, ProcessName, UserName)) {
      $properties = @{ 'PID'=$p.Id;
                       'ProcessName'=$p.ProcessName;
                       'UserName'=$p.UserName;
                     }
      $psobj = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $properties
      $obj+=$psobj
  }

Get-NetTCPConnection | where {$_.State -eq "Established"} | select `
  RemoteAddress, `
  RemotePort, `
  @{n="PID";e={$_.OwningProcess}}, @{n="ProcessName";e={($obj |? PID -eq $_.OwningProcess | select -ExpandProperty ProcessName)}}, `
  @{n="UserName";e={($obj |? PID -eq $_.OwningProcess | select -ExpandProperty UserName)}} |
  sort -Property ProcessName, UserName |
  ft -auto
```

Here's a screenshot with some sample output:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: There's a code review stackexchange site that this might be more appropriate for FYI.  Cool idea btw.

Comment: I wasn't aware. Sorry if this post is OT. Mods, feel free to move it!

Answer (score 12):

```
get-nettcpconnection | select local*,remote*,state,@{Name="Process";Expression={(Get-Process -Id $_.OwningProcess).ProcessName}}
```

I can't take credit for this solution, I found it here: https://superuser.com/questions/1215093/powershell-one-liner-to-show-process-on-same-line-as-port-using-netstat-issue/1215237

Comment: you can, as you searched and provided it here

Answer (score 4):

The pattern:

```
$a = @()
foreach ($x in Get-Thing|..) {
    $z = ..
    $a += $z
}
```

is not a great one, because `+=` on an array does a lot of in-memory copying of everything to a new array, so it can be surprisingly slow. `foreach() {}` can sometimes run faster than `| ForEach-Object {}` but if you have a pipeline inside the () part and array addition going on, it's possibly not going to make much difference there. Typical alternatives:

```
$a = foreach ($x in Get-Thing|..) {
    $z = $x...
    $z
}
```

or

```
$a = Get-Thing | .. | ForEach-Object {
    $_..
}
```

The first half of your script does approximately nothing:

- starts with an array of process objects
- filters out ones with no username, even though the empty usernames wouldn't change anything later on in your script
- selects three properties, copying them from one object into a new custom object, even though the script wasn't going to be affected by the other properties being there.
- takes those same three properties out into a hashtable ..
- converts that hashtable back into a custom object, putting you back where you were after the select.
- puts it back into another array, but slowly.

Original: process objects in an array.

Result: tweaked process objects in an array, changed, but not meaningfully so given the way you use them.

So you could drop all that for just `$obj = Get-Process -IncludeUsername` and it would work the same.

- You don't need as many backticks for line continuation. PowerShell is pretty good at continuing lines where it makes sense - after pipes `|`, and after commas in arrays, including `select` property arrays. It's good because the backtick breaks if there are any spaces after it, which is hard to see.

But if you want pre-processing to make the rest of the script nicer, use a hashtable, then the lookup in the second part becomes shorter and clearer:

```
# Make a lookup table by process ID
$Processes = @{}
Get-Process -IncludeUserName | ForEach-Object {
    $Processes[$_.Id] = $_
}

Get-NetTCPConnection | 
    Where-Object { $_.State -eq "Established" } |
    Select-Object RemoteAddress,
        RemotePort,
        @{Name="PID";         Expression={ $_.OwningProcess }},
        @{Name="ProcessName"; Expression={ $Processes[[int]$_.OwningProcess].ProcessName }}, 
        @{Name="UserName";    Expression={ $Processes[[int]$_.OwningProcess].UserName }} |
    Sort-Object -Property ProcessName, UserName |
    Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Anyway, now this comes out as the same answer as @avvi, I had to stop with it written but broken because I couldn't make it work until I saw their answer - Get-Process returns the Id as a number and Get-NetTCPConnection returns the OwningProcess as a string, so there needs to be a conversion for the hashtable lookup.

Posting anyway for the discussion about the looping / array building.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was struggling with ArgumentTransformationMetadataException errors with my own implementation.  Using your code as a starting point I've extended it to query both udp and tcp daemons and their associated processes.  See it here http://jcutrer.com/howto/dev/powershell/network-daemons-parent-processes

Comment: @JC_ thank you! - That's a cool script, I use netstat quite a lot and will try using that too :)

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find the question in Code Review, so I'm posting answer here for the moment.

Using a dictionary (hashtable) simplifies the expression and improves the lookup time per pid.

```
$dict=@{}

Foreach($p In (Get-Process -IncludeUserName | where {$_.UserName -ne $null} | `
  select Id, ProcessName, UserName)) {
      $properties = @{ 'PID'=$p.Id;
                       'ProcessName'=$p.ProcessName;
                       'UserName'=$p.UserName;
                     }
      $psobj = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $properties
      $dict[$p.Id] = $psObj

  }

Get-NetTCPConnection | where {$_.State -eq "Established"} | select `
  RemoteAddress, `
  RemotePort, ` 
  @{n="PID";e={$_.OwningProcess}}, 
  @{n="ProcessName";e={ $dict[[int]$_.OwningProcess].ProcessName }}, `
  @{n="UserName"; e={ $dict[[int]$_.OwningProcess].UserName }} |
  sort -Property ProcessName, UserName | ft -auto
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-NetTCPConnection| 
Select LocalAddress, LocalPort, RemoteAddress, RemotePort, State, OwningProcess 
, @{n="ProcessName";e={(Get-Process -Id $_.OwningProcess).ProcessName}} 
, @{n="UserName";e={(Get-Process -Id $_.OwningProcess -IncludeUserName).UserName}}| 
Where {$_.State -eq"Established"} 
|FT -autosize -Force
```

Cleaner than clean. Add the back tick (`) at the end of each line or remove carriage returns and put on one line. Backticks here seem to throw off the formatting such that you have to add two backticks (``) to keep the formatting.